# Maven sometimes fails sometimes succeed

Tags: java, maven

This question is like [maven compile sometimes fail and sometimes succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608302/maven-compile-sometimes-fail-and-sometimes-succeed) except that I don't have lombok in my project.

Also, I'm running `mvn clean verify` from the command line every time. It fails with `Unresolved compilation problem`. Could it be something else is tampering with my build directory or something?

I tried cleaning `~/.m2` so it downloads every dependency again but that didn't do it.

These are the errors I get

```
  MessageBuilderTest.nullTimestampThrowsError:135 »  Unresolved compilation prob...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDAnonymousIdThrowsException:115 »  Unresolved compil...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.nullUUIDMessageIdThrowsException:47 »  Unresolved compilati...
  MessageBuilderTest.providingUserIdBuildsSuccessfully:161 »  Unresolved compila...
  MessageBuilderTest.providingUserIdBuildsSuccessfully:161 »  Unresolved compila...
  MessageBuilderTest.providingUserIdBuildsSuccessfully:161 »  Unresolved compila...
  MessageBuilderTest.providingUserIdBuildsSuccessfully:161 »  Unresolved compila...
```

[Full error message here](https://gist.github.com/pbassut/078e03fa3ae759a28d26d39a72a35b3)

When I go to any of these, they have calls to deprecated methods. But those should be okay to be used(right?).

What could possibly be the cause here?

`mvn -version` returns:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 11.0.9, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.9/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

**EDIT:**

Something interesting I noticed: looks like the error only happens when I have VSCode with project opened in it. VSCode has [Java Extension Pack installed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). Maybe that's a hint?

Comment: Please show the complete error messages.

Comment: @tgdavies I tried but SO questions are limited to 3k characters. That's the bulk of it. The error message goes over 30k. I'll put it in a gist

Comment: Done. I edited the question to include the gist

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Are you able to make a self contained example which replicates it?

Comment: Simply fix your compilation issues....

Comment: @tgdavies Not really. It seems to be an environment issue. When I spin up the same project under an ubuntu VM, the command is pure again.

Comment: I edited it with some info about VSCode being open and maven versions